# Java 8 date expressions

Tags: java

JSR 310 brought us a nice datetime API to Java 8. I was wondering if there is some sort of expression language to create e.g. a `java.time.LocalDate` by using

```
now + 2y
```

which would be similar to

```
LocalDate.now().plusYears(2)
```

Is there such a feature in Java?

The question might be a bit broad but let me explain a bit further. I was looking for some sort of expression that I could apply on e.g. a `LocalDate`. It turns out there is `Duration` & `Period`.

Meaning I can define a period based on a standardized ISO-8601 format such as `P2Y`.

If I then do something like

```
LocalDate.now().plus(Period.parse("P2Y"));
```

With this I get the very basic behavior I was looking for.

Comment: Nope. Otherwise there would be a general operator overloading in Java

Comment: @ernest_k While as a statement this could not work, it could very well work as a string literal being passed as argument. Such an API could be written, given proper motivation.

Comment: @ernest_k my question was a bit broad. I was looking for a feature not a specific method on LocalDate.

Describing time periods or having a small date/time expression language does not seem very long shot and could be very useful.

Comment: One thing is to use a different JVM language (even for just one class). In Groovy, you can code `LocalDate.now() + 2` or `LocalDate.now() + Period.ofDays(2)`, `LocalDate.now() - Period.ofDays(2)`; and get expected results

Answer (score 1):

(Answer because comments are too small and unformatted)

While I do not know of such an API, one could exist, though you'd have to pass some sort of language-like objects (for example String-literals) into the method to define what you want.

It could look like this:

```
DateTimeUtil.offset("+2y");
```

Such an API could do a lot more:

```
Calendar oldCalendarObject = ...;
DateTimeUtil.shift("+2y+6M-6d");
```

Could be done with regex parsing, so it is not even that complicated.

```
public class DateTimeUtil {
    private static final Pattern SHIFT_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\s*([+-])(\\d+)([yMdmsn])\\s*");

    public static void shift(Calendar cal, String shift) {
        Matcher matcher = SHIFT_PATTERN.matcher(shift);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            boolean positive = matcher.group(1).equals("+");
            int num= Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(2));
            String unit = matcher.group(3);
            // do modification here.
        }
    }
}
```